# Method containing foreach statment to have only one return

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, return

I have following method prepared for unit tests and i know it will always run for-each loop, is there a way to get rid of second return statement?

```
public Enums.GYRStatus GetStatusForTransformer(
            string factoryCode, 
            Enums.Technology technology, 
            string transformerType,
            int transformerSize,
            string transformerModel)
{
   fakeStandardsAndSizesFictionary = new Dictionary<Tuple<string,
                                                    Enums.Technology,
                                                    string, int, string>, int>() 
   {
       { Tuple.Create("SELUD", Technology.CVT,"---", 0, ""), 1} };
   }

   foreach (var pair in fakeStandardsAndSizesFictionary)
   {
       if (pair.Key.Item1 == factoryCode &&
          pair.Key.Item2 == technology &&
          pair.Key.Item3 == transformerType &&
          pair.Key.Item4 == transformerSize &&
          pair.Key.Item5 == transformerModel)
           return (Enums.GYRStatus)pair.Value;
   }
   return (Enums.GYRStatus)1; // second return never used
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace

```
return (Enums.GYRStatus)1;
```

with

```
throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

It also looks more correct semantically, assuming that this place should never be reached.

Comment: sorry :o didn't noticed that my edit removed the last statement... I feel bad now :c

Comment: @MischaBehrend No problem at all, I accepted the edit and re-added the sentence. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `(GYRStatus)1` is a valid return value, you could do:

```
GYRStatus status = GYRStatus.First;
foreach (var pair in fakeStandardsAndSizesFictionary)
{
   if (pair.Key.Item1 == factoryCode &&
   pair.Key.Item2 == technology &&
   pair.Key.Item3 == transformerType &&
   pair.Key.Item4 == transformerSize &&
   pair.Key.Item5 == transformerModel)
   {
      status = (Enums.GYRStatus)pair.Value;
      break;
   }
}
return status;
```

You could also return a `GYRStatus?` to indicate no value was selected:

```
GYRStatus? status = null;
foreach (var pair in fakeStandardsAndSizesFictionary)
{
   if (pair.Key.Item1 == factoryCode &&
   pair.Key.Item2 == technology &&
   pair.Key.Item3 == transformerType &&
   pair.Key.Item4 == transformerSize &&
   pair.Key.Item5 == transformerModel)
   {
      status = (Enums.GYRStatus)pair.Value;
      break;
   }
}
return status;
```

Or, you could have a `GYRStatus.None` value in your enum as well. It all depends on the flow of execution. If it is possible that you may end up not finding a value with your predicate, return a default value instead of throwing an exception. If it isn't possible, throw.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
public Enums.GYRStatus GetStatusForTransformer(string factoryCode,   Enums.Technology technology, string transformerType, int transformerSize, string transformerModel)
{
    fakeStandardsAndSizesFictionary = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, Enums.Technology, string, int, string>, int>() 
    {
        {Tuple.Create("SELUD",Technology.CVT,"---",0 ,""),1},
    };

    return fakeStandardsAndSizesFictionary
        .Where(pair =>
            pair.Key.Item1 == factoryCode
                && pair.Key.Item2 == technology
                && pair.Key.Item3 == transformerType
                && pair.Key.Item4 == transformerSize
                && pair.Key.Item5 == transformerModel)
        .Select(pair => (Enums.GYRStatus)pair.Value)
        .First();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, even if you know that it will always return, the compiler doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for the compiler to know that the loop ALLWAYS returns a value. Therefor you have to provide that switch also.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Enums.GYRStatus GetStatusForTransformer(
            string factoryCode, 
            Enums.Technology technology, 
            string transformerType,
            int transformerSize,
            string transformerModel)
{
   Enums.GYRStatus retValue=(Enums.GYRStatus)1;
   fakeStandardsAndSizesFictionary = new Dictionary<Tuple<string,
                                                    Enums.Technology,
                                                    string, int, string>, int>() 
   {
       { Tuple.Create("SELUD", Technology.CVT,"---", 0, ""), 1} };
   }

   foreach (var pair in fakeStandardsAndSizesFictionary)
   {
       if (pair.Key.Item1 == factoryCode &&
          pair.Key.Item2 == technology &&
          pair.Key.Item3 == transformerType &&
          pair.Key.Item4 == transformerSize &&
          pair.Key.Item5 == transformerModel)
           retValue = (Enums.GYRStatus)pair.Value;
   }
   return retValue; 
}
```